# Z-Index is ignored on child absolute positioned div in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, z-index

I'm trying to use absolute positioning nested in a table cell that "pops up" when mousing over it. The following works great in Firefox, but for some reason fails in Google Chrome. It looks like the absolute positioned *text* ignores its z-index, and appears "over" the higher-z-indexed div.

```css
#c1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#c2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.cell:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 100;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell" id="c1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="absolute">TEST</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cell" id="c2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="absolute">TEST2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/323/

Is there anything I can do to avoid this, short of avoiding absolute positioning?

Comment: I removed the table from the sample because it didn't look like it changed the problems, as can be seen http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/322/

Comment: `z-index` only works with `position` give `position:relative;` on class `.cell:hover`. It will work on chrome too. But its weird behavior by Firefox.

Comment: @KheemaPandey That doesn't fix the issue on mouse-out for Firefox, and also doesn't fix the text appearing in mouse-out for Chrome, either.

Comment: yeah man you are right..on mouseout same bug appearing.. I didn't notice that.. thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.cell:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

this z-index is not working because .cell has a static position. 
Add position:relative to the cell class.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/326/)

Add `position:relative` to your `.cell` class.
This causes to `z-index` works.
Also it's better to use `transform` and `transition` or `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transition` for Google Chrome

Comment: Why would it be better to use a non-standard implementation over a standard one given that Chrome implements both?

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, with position: relative;. Note that you will still have z-index "issues" on hover out, but it still works pretty well.

Comment: @BoltClock just curious which browser is right in this case, Chrome or Firefox.. It seems Firefox having weird behavior.

Comment: although thats also true, `z-index` won't work without using `position`

Comment: @BoltClock All people doesn't use the last version of browsers. so It's better to use vendors prefix like `-o-`, `-ms-`, `-moz-` ,...

Comment: Adding `position: relative` to `.cell` *does* fix the issue completely in Chrome, but doesn't do anything for the bugginess in Firefox, unfortunately. However, I can't upvote you because you incorrectly suggest that it's better to use prefixed versions of `transition`. If they need to be added, fine, but it's wrong to *replace* the standards version, which should **always** be used.

Comment: agree with @TylerH. I am also in favour of using standard.

Comment: My website just needs to work under Google Chrome 41+, so -webkit-transform isn't a big deal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the answer here is to add `position: relative;` to your parent `.cell` element.

Why? Because adding a position to the parent element traps all child elements to a new stacking context.

Remember `z-index` values are relative to their stacking context — not necessarily root HTML document (they can be though). **Philip Walton** explains this in much greater detail within his post, [*"What No One Told You About Z-Index".*](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) Here are the key portions though:

> Here are the basic rules to determine stacking order within a single stacking context (from back to front):
>   1. The stacking context’s root element
>
> 2. Positioned elements (and their children) with negative z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)
> 3. Non-positioned elements (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
> 4. Positioned elements (and their children) with a z-index value of auto (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
> 5. Positioned elements (and their children) with positive z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)
>
> ---
>
> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order. **That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a z-index of a billion!**
>
> New stacking contexts can be formed on an element in one of three ways:
>
> - When an element is the root element of a document (the `<html>` element)
> - When an element has a position value other than `static` and a z-index value other than `auto`
> - When an element has an `opacity` value less than 1

***(Emphasis mine)***

I've updated your snippet below.

```css
#c1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#c2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.cell {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.cell:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 100;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell" id="c1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="absolute">TEST</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cell" id="c2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="absolute">TEST2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "When an element has an opacity value less than 1"

That's quite strange. Why would opacity value less than 1 create a new stacking context ?